# receiving a Specific value from other class which is not connected

Tags: java, methods

I have to create a Checkers board game and I have 4 classes:

1. Cell(for representing an empty cell it returns a toString ".")
2. White(represents a white cell and it returns toString "W")
3. Black(represents a black cell and it returns toString "B")
4. Checkers(Which sets up the board(Cell[8][8]) and initializes it.

I am having problem with calling in the empty, white and black cells which is represented by letters `.,W,B`. I have more work to do on the code but I just need help in calling those methods

The cell, Black and WHite classes looks like these:

```
  public class Cell {
 public static final String EMPTY=".";

 int i;
 int j;
 String value;

 public Cell(int i, int j){
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    value = EMPTY;
 }

 public String toString(){
    return value;
 }
}
```

And in the Checkers Class I have these methods: I just dont know how to call those from other classes so I just created a Another char array and put those values in. I know i have to work more on this.

```
    /*********initialization******/
public void init(){
    board = new Cell[8][8];


    char[][] a =
        {
            getEmptyWhite("EW"),
            getEmptyWhite("WE"),
            getEmptyWhite("EW"),
            getEmptyWhite("EE"),
            getEmptyWhite("EE"),
            getEmptyWhite("BE"),
            getEmptyWhite("EB"),
            getEmptyWhite("BE")

        };
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


    public char[] getEmptyWhite(String a){
        Cell empty;
        Black black;
        White white;    
        if(a.equals(empty)){
            char[] emptyWhite = {'E','E','E','E','E','E','E','E'};
            return emptyWhite;
        }
        else if(a.equals("EW")){
            char[] emptyWhite = {'E','W','E','W','E','W','E','W'}; 
            return emptyWhite;
        }
        else if(a.equals("EB")){
            char[] emptyWhite = {'E','B','E','B','E','B','E','B'};
            return emptyWhite;
        } else if(a.equals("WE")){
            char[] emptyWhite = {'W','E','W','E','W','E','W','E'};
            return emptyWhite;          
        } else if(a.equals("BE")){
            char[] emptyWhite = {'B','E','B','E','B','E','B','E'};
            return emptyWhite;          
        } 
        return null;
    }



/*********initialization ended*******/
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: White and black classes are extensions from Cell class? It is easier to manipulate your game if white and black classes extends from Cell

Comment: Yes white and black extends cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `getEmptyWhite`, it looks like instead of this line:

```
if(a.equals(empty)){
```

you should be using this:

```
if(a.equals("EE")){
```

Note that in the code that you posted, `empty` is a variable of type `Cell` with a value of `null`. Thus, `a.equals(empty)` will always be `false`. Also, you don't really need the local variables `empty`, `black`, and `white`.

Comment: If I don't  have those then how am i gonna print the board like that.

Comment: @SyedMudabbir - You're printing the two-dimensional `char[][]` array built from what's returned by `getEmptyWhite`. I don't see anywhere in your code that you are using the variables `empty`, `white`, or `black`.

Comment: Thank you I have to figure out a way to call those values thats what i was not sure of how to exactly call.

Thank you for your help.